# SQL Server Logical File Name usages?

Tags: sql-server

I'm restoring a Bak file

```
RESTORE DATABASE WEbERP2 FROM DISK = 'c:\r\WEbERP_backup_201105210100.bak'
WITH REPLACE , MOVE 'WEbERP' TO 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\WEbERP2.mdf',
MOVE 'WEbERP_log' TO 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\WEbERP2_log.ldf',REPLACE
```

Im restoring it AS **WEbERP2**             //2 !!!

and it works.

the Db is opened as a new Db named :**WEbERP2**

But the logical name is still : **WebErp.**

I know that the functionality is fine .

But still I'm having trouble to understand its usages.

[image]

I know I can change it by :

```
ALTER DATABASE xxx MODIFY FILE (NAME=N...
```

But I want to understand its usages , and when its important to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logical filename is a database-unique identifier to identify the database files in T-SQL statements. It isn't important as such, and there is no important reason to change it.

However, it does allow you to know which is the MDF and LDF file without looking at physical names, or knowing the internal ID of the files.

More importantly, when you add filegroups and files to seperate indexes, data or add partitioning then the ability to have "WebERP_Indexes" and other names becomes useful

Comment: `it does allow you to know which is the MDF and LDF file without looking at physical name` ?? so why the key is editable ? I still didnt understand when MUST i change it

Comment: 1. It isn't the key. The key is a number, this logical name is human readabl. Look for sys.database_files 2. There is no MUST reason to change it: you use the seven dwarves' names if you want...

Comment: So in the OP's case, does he need to worry about his WebERP2 db conflicting with WebERP db since they have the same logical filename?

Comment: @JohnWrensby: "The logical filename is a database-unique identifier " = does not matter if every database in your system has the same logical name

Comment: This thread was Closed for some reason, so I cannot post the accurate answer. But it is not true that the logical filename is not important! The logical filename is used in many cases. For example when we backup file we can use the logical filename, or when we are using DBCC CHECKDB the name is used in the error log, and so on.

Comment: In general (usually), if something exists, then most likely it has a reason :-)