# SQL Server: Function of database's logical name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Say my code looks like this:

```
create database name1 on (name = N'name2', filename = N'C:\SQL\name3')
```

name3 I understand.

Now, 'name2' is supposed to be the "logical name". From what I can find, this means that this is the appropriate name to refer to this database in database engine. However `USE name2`, returns an error. In contrast, `USE name1` works just fine.

The best answer I could find was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400568/sql-server-logical-file-name-usages), but it was closed before the answer could be clarified (what would be an example where I would use it rather than name1?).

My question: **What is the purpose of name2? When would I ever need to use it over name 1? Why is it a required component for file_spec?**

Thanks. (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Comment: @GordonLinoff What is it purpose? Please give an example where it would  be used.

Comment: . . It is used by `ALTER DATABASE`, if you want to remove the file or modify its properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A database can reside in multiple files, for example:

```
CREATE DATABASE DatabaseName 
ON  (NAME='LogicalName1', FILENAME='C:\SQL\PhysicalName1.mdf'), 
    (NAME='LogicalName2', FILENAME='C:\SQL\PhysicalName2.mdf')

GO
USE DatabaseName
SELECT * FROM sys.database_files
```

In the above example, you can see that in addition to the two data files specified, a transaction log file was also created. This file has a different role than the data files (it records every change in the database, so it can be rolled-back if the transaction is not completed).

If you use multiple data files (in the same filegroup), they are both filled proportionally and this is useful for performance, if they are stored on separate disks.

If you use multiple data files in separate filegroups, you can specify the location of each table (and index), so you are able to place a table that is accessed more frequently on a separate, high-performance (and high-cost) disk.

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187087.aspx for details.

As Gordon already said, the logical file name is used in the ALTER DATABASE statement, when you need to refer to a particular file. Using this command, you may change the size of the file, the auto-growth settings or put a particular file offline. Also, you can move the file to another physical location. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522469.aspx